# Single replacement for: "Upload a document" and "Upload a Video"

Tags: website-design, buttons, microcopy, social-media, sharing

I need a single replacement, to place in GUI, that categorises both "document" and "video". I need to place in my website interface to replace:

> "Upload a document"...

and

> "Upload a video"....

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean an icon to graphically represent these two bits of text?

Comment: no not an icon.. just a single text replacement for these two with combined meaning

Comment: Upload Documentary...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK - so I'm going to play a slight joker card here. And you may not realize it but you're giving this answer away in the question.

I'm totally agreeing with @PhilipW and @Baa along the lines of just `Upload` - *but* with a simple twist which speaks volumes...

[image]

Upload **with an [ellipis](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9544/what-is-the-significance-of-the-three-dots-on-menus-and-buttons-and-how-to)** - which tells the user that there is something in the user interface which is an extra step between pressing the button and completing the action.

It hints that you don't need to care what it is that you are uploading before you click the button, because you'll have a chance to sort that out on the next step. It's equivalent to `Save As...` where you choose the format after hitting the button, or `Print...` where you choose the printer after clicking the button.

Comment: I think these 3 little dots have been mentioned recently.  However I'd be interested to know if there's any research indicating that users actually notice these dots...

Comment: @PhillipW I didn't get far with [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37916/is-there-any-evidence-that-people-really-notice-ellipses-in-computer-applications) on English.SE. Wrong SE maybe. You could try it here...

Comment: ... I've posted a question on it !

Answer (score 1):

"Upload File"

Of course that depends on your user demographics, but most people these days understand what a File is since that term has been used forever.

Simply "Upload" could work as well.

I would not recommend using only an icon for the button, however. There is no well-recognized symbol to depict this type of action.

Answer (score 1):

Would "Upload Media" make sense for your case? If not I agree with Baa that "Upload" alone should be enough...

But I do think that an upward pointing arrow has become standard for upload, no?

Answer (score 1):

"Upload"

Upload being the action your carrying out.

Answer (score 1):

`Upload Item` or `Upload Content` should work..