# Is there any research on whether users understand ellipses (...)?

Tags: gui-design, research

This GUI design pattern goes right back to the Apple Lisa in the early 80s:

[image]

Is there any research covering:

1. Whether people actually notice the three dots (...) at the end of a menu item or button?
2. Whether people understand what they are supposed to signify?

Comment: A question has been asked which covers some of this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9544/what-is-the-significance-of-the-three-dots-on-menus-and-buttons-and-how-to

Comment: The previous answers seem to cover: 'why are they there ? ' - and the answer seems to be 'its in the interface design guidelines'.  Here I'm focussing on whether users actually see and understand them.

Comment: Think you mean "ellipsis" - the three dots...?

Comment: It's ellipses, because it's plural.

Comment: You live and learn, I stand corrected :-).

Comment: Comparing the content of the accepted answer from the linked question with the example screenshot here, it seems that they had a different purpose here, or different usage guidelines.  I am not a Mac guy at all, but the two items that each use an ellipsis probably don't require further information to be performed (especially, the menu item "Attributes of <paper> ..." item).  I think if anything, you are probably better to omit them, instead of implying something that may not be well understood.

Comment: I think this is a good point.  I've been looking at the usage of ellipses more closely recently - and they don't seem to be used consistently, even on more up to date software.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I notice and use it.

If a command does not have the elipsis, I think twice before I click it to be sure I know what it does (because no elipsis indicates that some actual action is performed if I click on it).

If the elipsis is there, I can click on it if I don't know exactly what it does to at least find out more in the next step.