# What are the rules of using ellipsis on buttons

Tags: buttons, guidelines, copywriting, labels

I read about the [rules of using ellipsis (three dots ...) in a menu command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511502.aspx#ellipses):

> Indicate a command that needs additional information (including a
>   confirmation) by adding an ellipsis at the end of the label.

I wonder if there are rules/convention/recommendation of using them on a button's label, outside of a menu.

It seems that there is no use of ellipsis in Ribbons in Microsoft products, even though some of the button do initiate a process which requires additional information (see example below).

So when considering the label of a command button which requires additional information in a pop-up dialog, would you recommend adding ellipsis at the end?

[image: Ellipsis is missing from the "Header and Footer" button]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the significance of the three dots "..." on menus and buttons and how to use them right?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9544/what-is-the-significance-of-the-three-dots-on-menus-and-buttons-and-how-to)

Comment: I've specifically asked about buttons, apart from commands on menues

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The very page you link to says:

> This doesn't mean you should use an ellipsis whenever an action
> displays another window—only when additional information is required
> to perform the action. For example, the commands About, Advanced,
> Help, Options, Properties, and Settings must display another window
> when clicked, but don't require additional information from the user.
> Therefore they don't need ellipses.

ie - in your example: *Header and Footer* is a button that does what it says - it brings up the header and footer information. It doesn't need additional information on order to bring up that dialog - it just does it - so it doesn't need an ellipsis.

The [Mac OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/TerminologyWording.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH15-SW3) state (And I've not included *all* the text here)

> Use an ellipsis in the name of a button or menu item when the
> associated action
>
> - Requires specific input from the user.
>
>   You can think
>   of commands of this type as needing the answer to a specific question
>   (such as "Find what?") before executing.
> - Is performed by the user in a separate window or dialog.
>
>   To see why
>   such commands must include an ellipsis, consider that the absence of
>   an ellipsis implies that the application performs the action for the
>   user. For example, if the Customize Toolbar command does not include
>   an ellipsis, it implies that there is only one way to customize the
>   toolbar and the user has no choice in the matter.
> - Always displays an alert that warns the user of a potentially
>   dangerous outcome and offers an alternative.
>
>   For example, Restart, Shut Down, and Log Out all use an ellipsis
>   because they always display an alert that asks the user for
>   confirmation and allows the user to cancel the action. Note that Close
>   does not have an ellipsis because it displays an alert only in certain
>   circumstances (specifically, only when the document or file being
>   closed has unsaved changes).

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft's design guidelines pretty much explain why there aren't Ellipses on the ribbon:

> Commands: Indicate that a command needs additional information. Don't use an ellipsis whenever an action displays another window—only when additional information is required. For more information, see Command Buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa974176.aspx

But your question is about "rules for using ellipses..." which vary from platform to platform. The most widely used set of rules for ellipses are:

- Ellipses, by themselves, shouldn't be interactive. For example, if you have "more..." as a label, don't make the ellipses behave differently than the text.
- Don't use Ellipses by themselves as labels
- Ellipses in labels often indicate that something is in progress or that information is incomplete or truncated. Using them in other ways leads to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The latest guidance (early 2017) on MSDN is on the Windows Desktop Guidelines > Command Buttons webpage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742402(v=vs.85).aspx

There is an explicit section on the use of Ellipses (emphasis theirs):

> #### Using ellipses
>
> While command buttons are used for immediate actions, more information might be needed to perform the action. **Indicate a command that needs additional information (including confirmation) by adding an ellipsis at the end of the button label**.
>
> ```
> +------------+
> |  Print...  |
> +------------+
> ```
>
> In this example, the Print... command displays a Print dialog box to gather more information.
>
> ```
> +------------+
> |  Print     |
> +------------+
> ```
>
> By contrast, in this example the Print command prints a single copy of a document to the default printer without any further user interaction.

Also note:

> This doesn't mean you should use an ellipsis whenever an action displays another window—only when additional information is required to perform the action.

So here's a simple human-program for you to follow:

```
Do you wish for the user to invoke an "immediate action"?
If yes then:
    Does this immediate action *always require* additional information before starting?
    If yes then:
        Use a command button with trailing ellipsis
    If no then:
        Use a command button without trailing ellipsis
If no then:
    Use a different UI control
```