# How to add UI elements that have a button which need a description and inform the user that steps will follow after clicking the button.

Tags: interaction-design, buttons

I have a button which requires a description. I currently have it as following

### [image]

But it looks unbalanced. 
Also this is not the final step of the procedure. I want the user to know that further steps will follow. How do I achieve this.

Comment: What is the purpose of the description? It doesn't appear to add much value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process involves a number of steps than this should be made explicit early on for example as in the mockup below:

[image]

Past this point a progress bar is a good idea ([Staged disclosure](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/)) as it provides the user with information about the number of steps within the process and has the advantage of making users feel they have made progress towards a a final goal (Endowed Progress Effect).

Do bear in mind that:

> Staged disclosure is useful when you can divide a task into distinct
>   steps that have little interaction. It is problematic when the steps
>   are interdependent and users must alternate between them.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

When more information or steps are needed to complete an action, **[is is convention](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9544/what-is-the-significance-of-the-three-dots-on-menus-and-buttons-and-how-to)** on most platforms including Windows and OS X that an ellipsis is added to the end of the label. This tells the user to expect further options after selecting the action. For example "**Go live...**".